# Why does 'perl -F,' work differently from 'perl -F<space>'

Tags: perl

This does what I expect (put --- when column2 changes value):

```
$ (echo 'a,,b';echo 'b,,a';echo 'c,a,b') |
    perl -a '-F,' -pe 'BEGIN{$last="---\n";}{local$_=$F[1];if(($last)ne$_){print"---\n";$last=$_;}}'
---
a,,b
b,,a
---
c,a,b
```

This does not:

```
$ (echo 'a  b';echo 'b  a';echo 'c a b') |
    perl -a '-F ' -pe 'BEGIN{$last="---\n";}{local$_=$F[1];if(($last)ne$_){print"---\n";$last=$_;}}'
---
a  b
b  a
c a b
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-a` is documented to using `split()`, and the perlfunc man page says this of it:

> As another special case, "split" emulates the default behavior of the command line tool awk when the PATTERN is either omitted or a string composed of a single space character (such as
> `' '` or `"\x20"`, but not e.g. `"/ /"`).  In this case, any leading whitespace in EXPR is removed before splitting occurs, and the PATTERN is instead treated as if it were `"/\s+/"`; in
> particular, this means that any contiguous whitespace (not just a single space character) is used as a separator.

So I suppose `-F\040` catches into that. For some reason, `[\040]` appears to also do that. (If I had to guess, I'd assume it gets optimized to a fixed string, and then treated as the special case.)

```
$ echo 'a b  c' | perl -a -F'\040'  -le 'print join(":", @F)'
a:b:c
$ echo 'a b  c' | perl -a -F'[\040]'  -le 'print join(":", @F)'
a:b:c
```

On the other hand, `\040{1}` seems to do what you want, and doesn't recognize tabs as separator:

```
$ echo 'a b  c' | perl -a -F'\040{1}'  -le 'print join(":", @F)'
a:b::c
$ printf 'a b\t c' | perl -a -F'\040{1}'  -le 'print join(":", @F)'
a:b     :c
```

Or I guess you could call `split` by hand explicitly with a pattern and not a string:

```
$ printf 'a b\t c' | perl -n -le '@F = split(/ /); print join(":", @F)'
a:b     :c
```

(I tested with Perl v5.24.1 and v5.28.1.)

Answer (score 1):

From `man perlrun`:

> -Fpattern [...] You can't use literal whitespace or NUL characters in the pattern.

But you *can* use \040:

```
$ (echo 'a  b';echo 'b  a';echo 'c a b') |   perl -a '-F\040' -pe 'BEGIN{$last="---\n";}{local$_=$F[1];if(($last)ne$_){print"---\n";$last=$_;}}'
---
a  b
---
b  a
c a b
```

Unfortunately it seems to be interpreted as one *or more* spaces (which is also the default for -F), which is not what I want.

`\s`  works better, but matches `\t`, too:

```
$ (printf 'a\t b\n';echo 'b  a';echo 'c a b') |   perl -a '-F\s' -pe 'BEGIN{$last="---\n";}{local$_=$F[1];if(($last)ne$_){print"---\n";$last=$_;}}'
---
a        b
b  a
---
c a b
```

Comment: Creepy! ... or `perl -a -F'\040' ... `

Comment: Ole, Space is the default Field Separator value?